# Count how many characters from a column appear in another column (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to count how many characters from the first column appear in second one. They may appear in different order and they should not be counted twice.

For example, in this df

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["AL0","CP1","NM3","PK9","RM2"],["AL0X24",
                            "CXP44",
                            "MLN",
                            "KKRR9",
                            "22MMRRS"]]).T
```

the result should be:

```
result = [3,2,2,2,3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other solutions will fail in the case that you compare names that both have the same multiple character, eg. `AAL0` and `AAL0X24`. The result here should be 4.

```
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["AL0","CP1","NM3","PK9","RM2", "AAL0"],
                        ["AL0X24", "CXP44", "MLN", "KKRR9", "22MMRRS", "AAL0X24"]]).T

def num_shared_chars(char_counter1, char_counter2):
    shared_chars = set(char_counter1.keys()).intersection(char_counter2.keys())
    return sum([min(char_counter1[k], char_counter2[k]) for k in shared_chars])

df_counter = df.applymap(Counter)
df['shared_chars'] = df_counter.apply(lambda row: num_shared_chars(row[0], row[1]), axis = 'columns')
```

Result:

```
      0        1  shared_chars
0   AL0   AL0X24             3
1   CP1    CXP44             2
2   NM3      MLN             2
3   PK9    KKRR9             2
4   RM2  22MMRRS             3
5  AAL0  AAL0X24             4
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `set.intersection` after zipping the 2 columns:

```
[len(set(a).intersection(set(b))) for a,b in zip(df[0],df[1])]
#[3, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

Comment: just realized `set.intersection` will be more efficient in terms of performance than `intersect1d` here :)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma may be, however I think you should retain your answer though.

Comment: I've tested it i guess `intersection` is around `10x` faster, not sure what's the reason is...got any clue?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma may be because or the fact that `intersect1d ` returns a sorted array- cost of sorting? , `Return the sorted, unique values that are in both of the input arrays` and there is an overhead compared to a builtin, not sure just guessing..!!

Comment: yeah..I think `sorting` step is adding the extra overhead in the runtime performance...`intersect1d` would be the better choice in case the output required should be sorted but here we are only concerned about the length of intersection.so i think `intersect1d` is unnecessary. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

Sticking to the dataframe data structure, you could do:

```py
>>> def count_common(s1, s2):
...     return len(set(s1) & set(s2))
...
>>> df["result"] = df.apply(lambda x: count_common(x[0], x[1]), axis=1)
>>> df
     0        1  result
0  AL0   AL0X24       3
1  CP1    CXP44       2
2  NM3      MLN       2
3  PK9    KKRR9       2
4  RM2  22MMRRS       3
```